# Синхронизация двух input с разными типами text и range

Tags: reactjs

Доброе время суток!

Подскажите, как синхронизировать два инпута. Без маски все отлично работает, а вот при подключении маски, range не двигается. Можно ведь использовать сторонюю библиотеку, но это не мой метод.

Маска разбивает числа по три.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const minmax ={
    minValue: 0,
    maxValue: 100000000
}

const Input= () =>{
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);    

    const maskInput = useRef();


    const handleChange = (e) =>{
        setPrice(e.target.value)
    }
 

    useEffect(() => {                
        setPrice(maskInput.current.value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " "))    
      }, [price]);
    
    return (
        <div>
        <input 
            type='text' 
            min={minmax.minValue} 
            max={minmax.maxValue}             
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} 
            value={price} 
            ref={maskInput}                        
        />

        <input 
            type='range' 
            min={minmax.minValue} 
            max={minmax.maxValue}            
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} 
            value={price}         
        />       
        </div>
    )
}

export default Input;
```

Comment: Создайте вторую переменную, которая будет числом без пробелов или собирайте число обратно.

Comment: судя по стейту, в него попадают как раз числа без пробелов

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему ползунок input range не работает?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1464857/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%ba-input-range-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82)

Answer (score 0):

Синхронизировать 2 input с разными значениями можно, для этого требуется преобразовать значения к тем, которые ожидаются в input.

Создаем вторую переменную состояния. Каждая переменная будет отвечать за свой формат данных.

```
const minmax = {
  minValue: 0,
  maxValue: 100000000
};

const Input = () => {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("0");
  const [priceRange, setPriceRange] = useState("0");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setPrice(e.target.value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " "));
    setPriceRange(e.target.value.replace(/\s/g, ""));
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        min={minmax.minValue}
        max={minmax.maxValue}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        value={price}
      />

      <input
        type="range"
        min={minmax.minValue}
        max={minmax.maxValue}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        value={priceRange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Второй вариант, для сокращения количества переменных и возможных рендеров, это преобразование значения непосредственно в render()

```
const Input = () => {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("0");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setPrice(e.target.value);
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        min={minmax.minValue}
        max={minmax.maxValue}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        value={price.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ")}
      />

      <input
        type="range"
        min={minmax.minValue}
        max={minmax.maxValue}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
        value={price.replace(/\s/g, "")}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Строка форматирования ведет себя странно, править не стал, ибо не знаю замысла автора вопроса, да и вопрос не в этом.

Comment: подсказали. надо  value={price.replace(/\s/g, "")} перевести в toString. вот правильно value={price.toString().replace(/\s/g, "")}

Comment: @AndreyMolodyk Добавьте в **handleChange** `console.log('type', typeof e.target.value)` и вы увидите, что тип данных и так **string**. Нет никакого смысла строку переводить в строку