# Почему ползунок input range не работает?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Буду благодарен, подскажите как ограничить длину ввода и почему не работает ползунок input type=range

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";   



const minmax ={
    minValue: 0,
    maxValue: 10000
}

const Input= () =>{
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);

    const maskInput = useRef();


    const handleChangeNumber = (e) =>{
        const numbers = e.target.value.replace(/(\D)/g, '');
        setPrice(numbers);        
        console.log('price ' + numbers);
    }
    const handleChangeRange = (e) =>{
        const numbers = e.target.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
        setPrice(numbers);        
        console.log('price ' + numbers);
    }

    useEffect(() => {                
        setPrice(maskInput.current.value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " "))
      }, [price]);
  
   
    return (
        <div>
        <input 
            type='text'                       
            onChange={(e) => handleChangeNumber(e)} 
            value={price} 
            ref={maskInput}                          
        />

        <input 
            type='range' 
            min={minmax.minValue}
            max={minmax.maxValue}
            onChange={(e) => handleChangeRange(e)} 
            value={price}                            
        />       
        </div>
    )
}

export default Input;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы в **управляемом** компоненте пытаетесь `value` устанавливать через `ref`, тем самым нарушаете логику React'а.
Вам не нужно использовать `ref` и `useEffect`.
см. комментарии ниже

```js
const minmax = {
  minValue: 0,
  maxValue: 10000,
};

const Input = () => {
  const [price, setPrice] = React.useState(0);
  //зачем  реф нужен? вы управляете компонентом через state
  //const maskInput = React.useRef();

  const handleChangeNumber = (e) => {
    const numbers = e.target.value;
    setPrice(numbers);
    //console.log("price " + numbers);
  };
  const handleChangeRange = (e) => {
    const numbers = e.target.value;
    setPrice(numbers);
    //console.log("price " + numbers);
  };
  /*
  React.useEffect(() => {
    //вы говорите реакту при рендере бери value из price, а потом пытаетесь его перезаписать через useEffect
    setPrice(maskInput.current.value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " "));
  }, [price]);*/

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => handleChangeNumber(e)}
        value={price.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ")} //value - это ваш стейт price, зесь же вы можете применить маску.
        /*ref={maskInput}*/       
      />

      <input
        type="range"
        min={minmax.minValue}
        max={minmax.maxValue}
        onChange={(e) => handleChangeRange(e)}
        value={price}
      />
    </div>
  );
};


const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<Input />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, работает